# Media Upload site on old laptop

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I have an old HP laptop with 1 gb ram and 100gb HDD

We need a space for our church's Photography team (usually only 1 or 2 people at a time) to upload the pictures they took.  The idea is to create a simple 1 page WordPress site that is hosted on a local pc and network, so they can access the website from their devices and simply upload via a form.

Is this device usable?
It is currently running windows vista, but I am able to install Linux. (which distro would be light weight and able to host a WordPress website?)

I am considering puppy linux?

Sorry I'm super new to pc's in general, would love some help.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad and unlikely to garner any answers.  Understand [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pc is probably okay to use, but the ram will not be enough to run the site and the operating system, [this](https://www.themeum.com/install-wordpress-localhost/) is a usefull tutorial for setting up a local wordpress site. if the wordpress sites run, you can share the static ip4 adress of the pc where wordpress is running on, follow this [tutorial](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180207/how-to-make-other-computer-in-local-network-see-my-theme#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Admin%20Panel%20%3E%20Settings,put%20your%20WAMP%20server%20online.&text=If%20you%20are%20enqueueing%20your,url%20in%20the%20style%20call.) if you are stuck.